# Why is fez's reputation showing up as -202 on the "Users" page?

Tags: bug, reputation, user-accounts

I looked up the user fez, and here is what the page showed:

[image: fez is shown with -202 reputation]

But when I clicked on it, fez's user page showed what seemed like the correct reputation (5,000 something).

Update: When I look it up again, it shows up the correct rep and all their badges and stuff. Why did it originally show -202 with no badges?

Comment: They gave a bounty?

Comment: @Adamant - That can't _possibly_ cause someone to go into the negatives, can it?

Comment: Adamant's answer below is obviously correct but it's worth noting that a user's reputation can't drop below 1 so if you ever see negative rep you're almost certainly not looking at total rep but rep over a period of time.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Right, I knew that rep couldn't drop below one. That's why I was very confused. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking at the reputation of the users in this calendar month, August. Since this user gave a bounty, their reputation in the last month has fallen.

[image]

Due to the numbers, it's evident that they probably gave a 200 reputation bounty ([on this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212627/51379)) and got one downvote.

Comment: Ohh! Thanks a bunch for this information! I thought I was looking at total rep there...